# RecursionError in the Tokenization of a large database in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I have a lot of txt files, so I made a dataset following this tutorial of tensorflow:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text?hl=es#build_vocabulary

My program works with smalls databases but when I use my database which have 4956 text files my program is finished when get to the part of the tokenization and sublime print:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
[Finished in 98.1s with exit code 3221225725]
```

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import os
import numpy as np
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))


#---PREPARING THE DATA --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

parent_dir=r'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\David\Programas\Sequence to tag 1st version\phon_o'
label=0
labeled_data_sets=[]

def labeler(example,index):
    return example,tf.cast(index,tf.int64)

for phase in os.listdir(parent_dir):
    phase_folder=os.path.join(parent_dir,phase)
    if phase == "training":
        for lan in os.listdir(phase_folder):
            lan_folder=os.path.join(phase_folder,lan)
            label=label+1
            for cor in os.listdir(lan_folder):
                cor_path=os.path.join(lan_folder,cor)
                for name in os.listdir(cor_path):
                    names_path=os.path.join(cor_path,name)
                    lines_dataset=tf.data.TextLineDataset(names_path)
                    #here I put the label
                    labeled_dataset=lines_dataset.map(lambda ex:labeler(ex,label))
                    labeled_data_sets.append(labeled_dataset)


BUFFER_SIZE=5000
BATCH_SIZE=64

#multiple datasets into one
all_labeled_data = labeled_data_sets[0]
for labeled_dataset in labeled_data_sets[1:]:
    all_labeled_data=all_labeled_data.concatenate(labeled_dataset)
print(all_labeled_data)


all_labeled_data.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)



#Tokenizer---------------------

#print()
#print('tokenizer')
tokenizer=tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()
vocabulary_set=set()

for text_tensor, _ in all_labeled_data:
    some_tokens=tokenizer.tokenize(text_tensor.numpy())
    vocabulary_set.update(some_tokens)


vocab_size=len(vocabulary_set)
print(vocab_size)
```

When I execute with my complete database the "vocab size" variable which is the len of the vocabulary dataset is not printed, I think something is wrong is the part of the tokenization, with small databases this work well, I tried to make it with tf.text but is not available to install on windows yet. Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the recursion depth in your code by including the following lines and try.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

You can know the recursion limit by just doing.

```
sys.getrecursionlimit()
```